# How do I speed up code to read exif data?

Tags: r, tiff

I am reading exif data from a large number of tif files in order to get the date each file was modified and return it as a list.  I am using the following code:

```
ref_img_path <- file_list[1]


exif_data<-exifr::read_exif(ref_img_path)
exif_data
modification_date <- exif_data$FileModifyDate
print(modification_date)


read_tif_modification_dates<-function(folder_path) {
  
  tif_files <- list.files(folder_path, pattern = ".tif", full.names = TRUE)

  
 timestamps<-list()
 
 for(tif_file in tif_files){
   exif_data <- read_exif(tif_file)
   modification_date_str<-exif_data$FileModifyDate
   modification_date<-as.POSIXct(strptime(modification_date_str, "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S"))
   timestamps[[tif_file]]<- modification_date
}
 
  return(timestamps)
}
  
  timestamps_list<-read_tif_modification_dates(folder_path)
```

It works fine with a folder that contains 11 images. It still works with a folder that contains 100,000, but takes hours.  is there a way to do this that will speed it up?

Comment: The biggest suggestion I'd make is to not use a `for` loop. Reading the help for `?read_exif`, it takes a `"A vector of filenames"` for the `path=` argument. So you can just call it once for the whole of `tif_files` I think. I can't guarantee it'll be faster, but if it pushes the loop for reading the files to compiled code it may well be.

Comment: Try running `exiftool` on its own in a Terminal, or Command Prompt, and it can parse all the TIFFs in a directory in one go - writing the results to a CSV or whatever you want.

Comment: Something like `exiftool -FileModifyDate  -ext tif -csv  . `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that "FileModifyDate" isn't actually an EXIF metadata tag. The underlying `exiftool` is just pulling that info from the file system. If that's all the information you need, you don't need to parse the EXIF data at all. You can run

```
file.info(tif_files)$mtime
```

as one statement to get the modified date/time values for all the files in one go. They will already be formatted as `POSIXct` values so you won't need to convert them explicitly to date/time vaues.